# Linear Indepence Question involving an arbitrary vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $u, v, w$ are linearly independent in $V$ and $x \in V$.
Prove $u + x, v + x, w + x$ are always linearly independent.

I'm stuck on this problem because I don't know what to do with $x$. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question [Prove that, if $\{u,v,w\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, then so is $\{u+v, v+w, u+v+w\}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994121/prove-that-if-u-v-w-is-a-basis-for-a-vector-space-v-then-so-is-uv)

Comment: I recommend changing "random" to "arbitrary" in the title. I thought the vectors were going to be random variables (as in probability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stuck because the result is false as it is stated now. Let ${\bf x} = -{\bf u}$, or the opposite of any of the other two vectors. If $\{{\bf u},{\bf v}, {\bf w}, {\bf x}\}$ is linearly independent, for example, it seems true, and follows straight from definition.  Maybe there is some other hypothesis we can add to fix this.

Comment: Thanks you're totally right! the question was asking if the statement was true or false.